# How can I access VM ware localhost in mobile?

Tags: angular, responsive-design, angular-material, vmware, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using VM ware for my development and I am doing some responsive design code.
I want to see it in action in my mobile rather than the web-developer tools responsive layout emulator.
I want to be able to access my VM localhost:port in mobile. I am very much new to this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to to this is to configure VM's network with Bridge network to connect it directly to your home network. Then you will need to connect your smartphone on the same network.

Comment: Thanks Charles for the response. Could you please tell me the steps to configure the same.

Comment: You should find enough information with this link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozwzO0pBjc4

Comment: It would be great if you could upvote the question